# jQuery mobile and pop up dialog boxes

Tags: jquery, mobile, dialog, jquery-mobile

I need a pop up dialog box for my jQuery mobile app. I found this plug in:

http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/

Which is awesome *-- doing exactly what I need, but for one detail --* it doesn't work correctly on the Android browsers I tried it on (all I get is a blank screen.) I suspect that the developer only tested on iPhone (perhaps an iPhone user could confirm if it works or not.)

Does anyone know of either a fix, or an alternative plug in that does the same sort of thing?

Comment: It worked on my android just fine.

Comment: May I ask what version of Android you are using, and what browser you used?

Comment: Android version 2.2.1, using the built-in browser.

Comment: Yeah, there was an issue that cropped up on the switch to beta - which I thought was fixed, apparently not entirely.  Make sure you are using the latest sources, and - how are you opening the dialog (specifically, what event are you listening to?  vclick, click, tap?)

Comment: Johnathan, as a test I am just simply using your web site above. Interestingly it doesn't work for the basic dialogs, but does work for the advanced. I have used it in my own code too, as a click response on an anchor and get the same problem.

Comment: Interesting.  actually, when I size down, I can duplicate this in chrome.  Give me a few hours, I should have a fix in a while (have to do the actual day job first :) )

Comment: Give it a shot again, making sure to reload all the pieces parts (clear cache if needed).  It was double "opening", with the second one empty. I also updated to beta1 instead of alpha 4.1

Comment: I downloaded the lastest from git and it worked a charm. Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are simply displaying information (no need for callback/response events) you can create a popup in this manner:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("<div class='ui-loader ui-overlay-shadow ui-body-e ui-corner-all'><h1><strong>Thank you, we have received your information.</strong></h1></div>")
    .css({ "display":"block", "opacity":0.96, "top": $(window).scrollTop() + 100 })
    .appendTo( $("body") )
    .delay( 2500 )
    .fadeOut( 400, function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This works very well! JQuery Mobile 1.2 alpha for popups still have some issues when combining with older version of JQuery Mobile.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem and I decided to use `popup()` function from jQuery Mobile 1.2 alpha: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0-alpha.1/docs/pages/popup/index.html. Before this I used JQM Simple Dialog 2 http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/demos2/.

**This might help also:**

I've also created a small plugin which wraps around jQuery Mobile `popup()` function to be able to call the popup much easier like `$.dynamic_popup('Your HTML message');` See http://ghita.org/jquery/dynamic-mobile-popup or the demo and screenshots at https://github.com/serbanghita/jQM-dynamic-popup

Let me know if you find it useful.

PS: works with jQM 1.3